# How to convert docker-compose setup to docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to convert docker-compose setup to docker image?

So i have a docker enviroment setup with `docker-compose` and i would like to create a docker image for [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) from that setup.

Is there a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't merge multiple images.

You can capture running containers as images with `docker commit`, and push each image to the Hub - but you'd need to share your `docker-compose.yml` separately.

There is a new workflow for this type of scenario called [application bundles](https://github.com/jeffhuys/moby/blob/2836d6decb02eea1f2ca4f7bfaf4f9ca87315f0f/experimental/docker-stacks-and-bundles.md), which lets you capture a distributed system as a bundle of images. It's currently an experimental feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can either build the image with `$ docker build` command and use the correct tag and push it with `$ docker push`. Or you can define the correct image in docker-compose.yml:

```
container:
   build: .
   image: username/image:tag
```

And after the build push the image with `$ docker-compose push`

Comment: The point is i have multiple containers in my docker-compose.yml and it does build multiple images. And i need one marged

Comment: I don't see any point of doing it that way. I assume different images (and containers) have different role so it would be clearer if they will use separated images. Of course I don't know the actual use case.

Comment: I would like to use this env at bitbucket pipelines